# Oracle ORA-01031: insufficient privileges while creating user

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, privileges, user-roles

I have created a user, let's call him C##USER from sysdba. Now, I'm trying to create another user from C##USER. Problem is I keep getting the following error:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

I have granted C##USER all privileges and have set the default role to ALL. Nothing works yet...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a `CREATE USER` system privilege BUT don't forget to use `CONTAINER`clause which should be set to `ALL`, if you omit this clause then the grantee will have `CREATE USER` system privilege on the current container.

> Specify CONTAINER = ALL to commonly grant a system privilege, object privilege on a common object, or role, to a common user or common role

[GRANT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#SQLRF01603)

When a common user account is created, the account is created in all of the open pluggable databases. So the user who is creating this new user must have `CREATE USER` system privilege on all containers.

```
SQL> grant create user to c##user container=all;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn c##user
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> create user c##user2 identified by user2;

User created.
```