# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges even though it has been granted the rights

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-xe

I have a user named BT_MASTER when connected to SYSTEM, and granted BT_MASTER the role MAIN_ADMIN_ROLE:

`select * from dba_role_privs where grantee = 'BT_MASTER';`

| GRANTEE | GRANTED_ROLE | ADMIN_OPTION | DELEGATE_OPTION | DEFAULT_ROLE | COMMON | INHERITED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BT_MASTER | MAIN_ADMIN_ROLE | NO | NO | YES | NO | NO |

This role, again using SYSTEM to GRANT, has the privilege to CREATE USER:

`select * from role_sys_privs`

| ROLE | PRIVILEGE | ADMIN_OPTION | COMMON | INHERITED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MAIN_ADMIN_ROLE | CREATE USER | NO | NO | NO |

However, when trying something simple like this, connected to the DB as BT_MASTER:

`CREATE USER new_user_example;`

I get this error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
> CREATE USER new_user_example
> Error report -
> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
> 01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
> the necessary privileges.
> *Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
> administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

I am using Oracle XE 18c, the slim version (gvenzl/oracle-xe:18-slim)

Does anyone know if this is a limitation of this version, or if I am doing something incorrect?

Comment: Is the role activated by default for the user, or do you need to turn it on explicitly with `SET ROLE MAIN_ADMIN_ROLE;` in your session?

Comment: I use SYSTEM to grant the role to BT_MASTER. Then, connecting as TB_MASTER, try and execute. create role.

Comment: Are you running the CREATE USER command inside a stored procedure by any chance?

Comment: I have also tried SET ROLE MAIN_ADMIN_ROLE, but no difference, still get the error

Comment: No, not inside a stored procedure. Just as is.

Comment: Try running `select * from user_role_privs` as BT_MASTER to make sure you have the role. And [see this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43301204/oracle-ora-01031-insufficient-privileges-while-creating-user) - your role and grant aren't `common`, so they only apply to the container that they were granted from.

Comment: I have ran that query when connected as BT_MASTER,  it tells me something similar to role_sys_privs, that MAIN_ADMIN_ROLE has been granted. I have tried to run GRANT CREATE ROLE to TB_MASTER container=all; using SYSTEM user, and the grant was successful, but still the same error when trying to create a user with BT_MASTER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this issue by connecting as SYSTEM and doing the following:

grant DBA to BT_MASTER with admin option;

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 21XE, but that shouldn't matter:

```
SQL> select banner from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production

SQL>
```

---

It usually helps if you post *everything* you did, step-by-step - then we can replicate it and (hopefully) spot the error. As you didn't do it, I tried to simulate the process. Have a look.

Connected as `SYS`, I'll create the `bt_master` user and a role (and grant appropriate privileges):

```
SQL> connect sys/pwd@pdb1 as sysdba
    Connected.
SQL> create user bt_master identified by bt_master
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to bt_master;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create role main_admin_role;

Role created.

SQL> grant create user to main_admin_role;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant main_admin_role to bt_master;

Grant succeeded.
```

It's all set; now, connect as `bt_master` and try to create a new user:

```
SQL> connect bt_master/bt_master@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create user bt_test identified by bt_test;

User created.

SQL>
```

As you can see, everything went just fine. Can you find the error in your steps? If not, do as instructed - post the whole process, just like I did.

Comment: I did the following connected as SYSTEM:

`create user bt_master identified by bt_master
default tablespace users
temporary tablespace temp
quota unlimited on users;

grant create session to bt_master;

create role main_admin_role;`

`grant create user to main_admin_role;`

`grant main_admin_role to bt_master;`

And then connected as bt_master, and still get the ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error.

Comment: Just to add, I use SQLDeveloper, and have tried the same as you when connecting as SYS, changing the role to SYSDBA, and executing what you have. I get the same result, ORA-01031: insufficient privileges. Could this be a lite issue?